# what is the value of an uninitialized static char in c?

Tags: c

The default value of an uninitialized `static int` is zero. What about if the datatype is a `char`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static char i;
    printf("%c", i);
    return 0;
}
```

This program executes without giving any output - why?

Comment: That's because `%c` isn't doing what you want and zero is not printable

Comment: Variables with static storage (globals and static) are zero initialized if not initialized explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, `i` is default initialized to zero, and when you output that **as a character** using `printf` with the `%c` format you are outputting the null character `\0`, which is why you don't see anything.

If you wanted to see the numerical value, you should use `printf("%i", (int)i)`

Comment: The cast is unnecessary. Unless explicitly specified otherwise, `char` is automatically promoted when passed as a variadic argument

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes I know that happens implicitly, I included the cast explicitly to emphasize what the statement is doing

Answer (score 2):

In C `static` variables are auto initialized.

- If it's of integer number type, like `int`, etc… It will be initialized to `0`.
- If it is of floating number type like `float`, etc... It will be initialized to `0.0`.
- If it's of `char` type then it will be initialized with null character, `\0`.
- If it's of pointer type it will get it's default value as  `NULL`